Generate all possible Boolean cases from n Boolean Values
If two fields exist, the corresponding fields are Boolean values.

x_field(bool value)
y_field(bool value)

I want to generate all cases that can be represented as a combination of multiple Boolean values.
For example, there are a total of 4 combinations that can be expressed by two Boolean fields as above.

x_field(true), y_field(true)
x_field(true), y_field(false)
x_field(false), y_field(true)
x_field(false), y_field(false)

If you have an array with two fields that are Boolean type, can you generate all cases and express like this form?
# before calculate ...
fields = ["x_field", "y_field"]

# after calculate ... 
result = [{"x_field": True, "y_field": True},
          {"x_field": True, "y_field": False},
          {"x_field": False, "y_field": True},
          {"x_field": False, "y_field": False},]


My Attempted
I thought I could solve this problem with the itertools module, but I wasn't sure which function to use.
I tried to implement using various itertools module functions, but it failed.
from itertools import combinations, permutations
boolean_fields = ["x_field", "y_field"]
# -->
boolean_fields = [True, False, True, False]
x = list(combination(boolean_fields, 2))


First, the result doesn't seem to be correct (a dictionary can't have more than one x_field/y_field). Second, could you show us the code with which you attempted to calculate the expected result?

I'm sorry about this. There was a my mistake.

I'm surprised no one has proposed this simple one-liner yet...
from itertools import product
fields = ['x', 'y', 'z']
[dict(zip(fields, values)) for values in product([True,False], repeat=len(fields))]

Output:
[{'x': True, 'y': True, 'z': True},
 {'x': True, 'y': True, 'z': False},
 {'x': True, 'y': False, 'z': True},
 {'x': True, 'y': False, 'z': False},
 {'x': False, 'y': True, 'z': True},
 {'x': False, 'y': True, 'z': False},
 {'x': False, 'y': False, 'z': True},
 {'x': False, 'y': False, 'z': False}]

Explanation:
product([True,False], repeat=len(fields)) creates all the 2**len(fields) combinations of True or False values.
Then iterating over these combinations, zip(fields, values) pairs up every field name to its corresponding value.
Finally turn every such pairing into a dict, and turn that into a list of dicts as you iterate over all the combinations (through list comprehension syntax).

That's the solution I wanted, thank you!!

Here's a solution using namedtuples and a little bit of bit magic:
from collections import namedtuple


def from_bit_field(obj_type: type, number):
    dict_obj = {}
    for field in obj_type._fields:
        # assign field with the last bit
        dict_obj[field] = bool(number & 1)
        # move to the next bit
        number >>= 1
    
    obj = obj_type(**dict_obj)
    return obj


def get_all_combos(*names: list[str]):
    Item = namedtuple("Item", names)

    result = []
    for number in range(2 ** len(names)):
        # numbers from 0 to 2**len-1 contain all possible bit combos
        result.append(from_bit_field(Item, number))
    
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_all_combos("x", "y", "z"))
    
    # namedtuples are convenient as they allow you to convert them to tuples
    print([tuple(i) for i in get_all_combos("x", "y", "z")])
    


It can be solved through named tuple. Thank you for your good answer.

The number of cases is 2^n where n is the number of fields.
and ssuming there's a syntax mistake and the result you'd like for the example provided is a Collection[Dict], i.e.:
# after calculate ... 
fields = [
  {"x_field": True, "y_field": True},
  {"x_field": True, "y_field": False},
  {"x_field": False, "y_field": True},
  {"x_field": False, "y_field": False},
]

The the simplest most straightforward (albeit not the most elegant or performant) way to approach it is to iterate over all cases:
def allCombinations(fields : list[str]) -> list[dict[str,bool]]:
    result = []
    for f1 in fields:
        temp = result
        result = []
        if not temp: result.extend([{f1:True},{f1:False}])
        else:
            for f2 in temp:
                result.extend([{**f2,f1:True},{**f2,f1:False}])
    return result



I think it's a good way to implement without using external libraries. Thank you for your answer!

Here's one way to solve it
# if you're in a python version without type hints,
# use `def combinations(fields):` instead
def combinations(fields: list[str]) -> list[dict[str, bool]]:
    out = []
    for field in fields:
        partials = out
        out = []
        if partials:
            # make new entries with the new field as True or False.
            # we need two lists, since modifying a list while
            # we're iterating through it leads to issues
            for entry in partials:
                out.append({**entry, field: True})
                out.append({**entry, field: False})
        else:
            # base care for empty list
            out.append({field: True})
            out.append({field: False})

    return out


fields = ["x_field", "y_field"]
print(combinations(fields))

outputs
[{'x_field': True, 'y_field': True},
 {'x_field': True, 'y_field': False},
 {'x_field': False, 'y_field': True},
 {'x_field': False, 'y_field': False}]

and for input ["a", "b", "c"]
[{'a': True, 'b': True, 'c': True},
 {'a': True, 'b': True, 'c': False},
 {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': True},
 {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': False},
 {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': True},
 {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False},
 {'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': True},
 {'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': False}]


Thank you for your answer, I made sure it was implemented well.
